# undefined method `loan_amount' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I am doing a `jewel loan` application using `ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [i686-linux]` and `Rails 4.2.1` in that i am having two models:

1)`jewelloan.rb`
2)`jltransaction.rb`

I have added foreign key `jewelloan_id` to get the `loan_amount` in jltransactions table. Where as `loan_amount` is a field in jewelloans table.

My problem is foreign key relationship not working. I have searched many stackoverflow questions to solve this but that are not working.

I have attached my model,view,controller and everything. Please tell me where i did a mistake.

**jewelloan.rb**

```
  class Jewelloan < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessor :transaction_amount

    attr_accessible :transaction_amount

    has_many :jltransactions, :dependent => :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :jltransactions ,:allow_destroy => true

    attr_accessible :account_number, :customer_name, :customer_address, :opened_on, :due_date, :amount, :jewel, :no_of_items, :gross_weight, :net_weight, :appraised_amount, :loan_amount, :transaction_mode, :transaction_type, :particulars, :comments, :close_date, :jltransactions_attributes

 end
```

**jltransaction.rb**

```
 class Jltransaction < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessor :loan_amount

    attr_accessible :loan_amount

    belongs_to :jewelloan 

    attr_accessible :transaction_date, :transaction_amount, :transaction_mode, :transaction_type, :particulars, :comments, :jewelloan_id

 end
```

**jewelloans_controller.rb**

```
 class JewelloansController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @jewelloan = Jewelloan.new
  end

  def create
    @jewelloan = Jewelloan.create(jewelloan_params)
    if @jewelloan.save
      flash[:success] = "Special JL was successfully created"
      redirect_to @jewelloan
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Special Jewel Loan was not created"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def jewelloan_params
      params.require(:jewelloan).permit(:account_number, :customer_name, :customer_address, :amount, :interest_rate, :opened_on, :due_date, :amount_due, :jewel, :no_of_items, :gross_weight, :net_weight, :appraised_amount, :loan_amount, :transaction_mode, :transaction_type, :particulars, :comments, :close_date, :no_of_days, :jltransactions_attributes)
    end

  end
```

**jltransactions_controller.rb**

```
 class JltransactionsController < ApplicationController

   def new    
     @jltransaction = Jltransaction.new
     @jewelloan = Jewelloan.new
   end

   def create
     @jltransaction = Jltransaction.create(jltransaction_params)  
     @jewelloan = @jltransaction.jewelloans(jewelloan_params)  
     if @jltransaction.save
       flash[:success] = "Transaction created"
       redirect_to @jltransaction
     else
       flash[:danger] = "Transaction was not created"
       render 'new'
     end
   end

 private
  def jltransaction_params
    params.require(:jltransaction).permit(:transaction_date, :transaction_amount, :transaction_mode, :transaction_type, :particulars, :comments, :jewelloan_id)
  end

 end
```

**app/views/jltransactions/_form.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_for @jltransaction do |jlt| %>

 <%= jlt.hidden_field :jewelloan_id, :value => @jewelloan.id %>

 <% if @jltransaction.errors.any? %>

 <h2>Transaction Failed</h2>
 <ul>

 <% @jltransaction.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>

 <li><%= error %></li>

 <% end %>

 </ul>

 <% end %>    

 <%= jlt.label :loan_amount %>
 for<%= jlt.text_field :loan_amount, :disabled => true, :value => @jltransaction.jewelloan.try(:loan_amount) %>

 <%= jlt.label :transaction_amount %>
 <%= jlt.text_field :transaction_amount %>

 <%= jlt.submit "Submit Transaction", class: "btn btn-success" %> 

  <% end %>
```

**rails console**

```
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 34ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `loan_amount' for nil:NilClass):
```

Please give some ideas to work the foreign key.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relationship might be returning nil result.
Try

```
@jltransaction.jewelloan.try(:loan_amount)
```

Comment: Now that field is shown but am not able to get the loan_amount.

Comment: Have you make sure that @jltransaction object has jewelloan record associated with it?

Comment: Still i am getting null value for the field loan_amount in my jltransactions table

Comment: Can you please paste result of @jltransaction.jewelloan ?

Comment: Jewelloan Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "jewelloans".* FROM "jewelloans" WHERE "jewelloans"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]                                             Started GET "/jltransactions/new?id=4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-29 14:56:02 +0530
Processing by JltransactionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"4"}

Comment: Where is result of query? I mean jewelloan object?

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SOB6lpeRRigi6hEqIZrH1yubCw50N1lVUWMu53tlz1A1JGP9DjgzqlptXULWdwJQeOOmecG3yAvA5eR1s1dbUg==", "jltransaction"=>{"jewelloan_id"=>"", "transaction_amount"=>"500", "transaction_mode"=>"Credit", "transaction_type"=>"Cash", "particulars"=>"TO JL NO:3", "comments"=>"Part amount."}, "commit"=>"Submit Transaction"}
Unpermitted parameter: jewelloan_id

Comment: This  "jltransaction"=>{"jewelloan_id"=>"",} shows that jltransaction does not have any jewelloan object associated with it. First assign jewelloan_id then try the same query

Comment: also add jewelloan_id to permit list

Comment: after added :jewelloan_id to permit list. Results the same this time unpermitted parameter: jewelloan_id didn't come

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rlHU6D8KKilgduk7efybJIlzSezOBDhBZDjrrIO9KjrTlc2DpqNfqxjxpVOOEV6j2gvkm3uEqR/1viE+S4++OA==", "jltransaction"=>{"jewelloan_id"=>"#<Jewelloan:0xb51d7224>", "transaction_amount"=>"1000", "transaction_mode"=>"Credit", "transaction_type"=>"Cash", "particulars"=>"TO JL NO:4", "comments"=>"Part amount."}, "commit"=>"Submit Transaction"}

Comment: I am getting jewelloan_id value = 0 in jltransactions table.

Comment: It looks like you are storing object itself in jewelloan_id instead of id of object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79123/discussion-between-triveni-badgujar-and-yogesh).

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
<%= jlt.text_field :loan_amount, :disabled => true, :value => @jltransaction.jewelloan.try(:loan_amount) if @jltransaction && @jltransaction.jewelloan %>
```

Comment: after i have tried: Processing by JltransactionsController#create as HTML
jltransaction"=>{"jewelloan_id"=>" " } Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2146ms (ActiveRecord: 104.7ms)

NameError (undefined local variable or method `jewelloan_params' for #<JltransactionsController:0xb5a9d0c0>):
  app/controllers/jltransactions_controller.rb:11:in `create'

Comment: Add strong params in `jltransactions_controller` like `jewelloan_attributes:[attributes....]`

Comment: In jltransactions_controller: @jewelloan = @jltransaction.jewelloans(jewelloan_params) this line is right?

Comment: added strong params but results are still the same

Comment: Add strong params in `jltransactions_controller`, It should be plural `jewelloans_attributes:[attributes....]`

Comment: Use this `@jewelloan = @jltransaction.jewelloans(jltransaction_params)`

Comment: I did it. But still am getting: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gOSHEm5AhwyXyXP/88S2LCfvvjOU+iVKLc5KjWuXelr9IJ559+nyju9OP5cEKXOrdJcTRCF6tBS8SIAfo6XuWA==", "jltransaction"=>{**"jewelloan_id"=>"#<Jewelloan:0xb5392708>"**, "transaction_amount"=>"3500", "transaction_mode"=>"Credit", "transaction_type"=>"Cash", "particulars"=>"TO JL NO:3", "comments"=>"Part amount."}, "commit"=>"Submit Transaction"}

Comment: If there is belongs_to association then how can we use
**@jewelloan = @jltransaction.jewelloans(jltransaction_params)**